# Unable to find specific text in meta tag using Selenium and Beatifulsoup

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="product-grid-item  ">

    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://undefeated.com/products/air-humara- 
     17-qs-silver-carotene-bluespark-black">
```

The code above is what I'm searching for, the word 'humara' is there.

```
from Utilities import custom_logger as cl
from Base.basepage import BasePage
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class NewShoePage(BasePage):

    log = cl.customLogger(logging.DEBUG)

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    def searchForKeywords(self, keywords):
        html = self.driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        keywordsFound = soup.find_all('meta', content=keywords)
        print(keywordsFound)
```

When I call:

```
searchForKeywords('humara')
```

It prints out nothing at all

I want to find the word 'humara' in the meta content tag on the web page, but it returns nothing. Once this is done, I would like to redirect to that link.

Comment: without knowing what page you are trying to get this data from, we can't help you. it may be something simple such as capitalization (`Nike` instead of `nike`), since these things are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def searchForKeywords(self, keywords):
    html = self.driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    possibleUrls = soup.find_all('meta', content=re.compile(keywords))
    for meta in possibleUrls:
        print(meta['content'])
```

The above code returns:

```
https://undefeated.com/products/air-humara-17-qs-silver-carotene-bluespark-black
```

Figured it out, I had to use re.compile and then loop through the urls and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need BeautifulSoup if you are already using Selenium.

`elements = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('nike')`

Comment: The 'a' tag that I'm trying to find is not displayed on the front end of the page, but it's in the html. When I hover over the element, then the 'a' tag text becomes visible and it would work then, but I don't want to do this. I want to search the entire html for the specific keyword in the hidden 'a' tag and then go to that link, hopefully that's more clear, thanks